# Error in price calculation C#

Tags: c#

I have a function like this

```
public static void PriceSchema (string standardprice, string quantity,string priceperpice)
{
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo english = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
    double dstandardprice = double.Parse(standardprice, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, english);
    double totalPRice = double.Parse(quantity) * double.Parse(priceperpice);
    double totalStandardPrice = dstandardprice*double.Parse(quantity);
    double savings = totalStandardPrice - totalPRice;
```

}

And I am calling it like

```
  XSLTHelper.PriceSchema("31.96", "10", "27.20");
```

But there is some thing going wrong in this line

```
  double totalPRice = double.Parse(quantity) * double.Parse(priceperpice);
```

totalPRice  was expected to be 272 but it produces an output `27200.0` .Can any one point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What is your current thread culture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you parse the standardPrice you are using the culture `en-US`, the `CultureInfo` variable you call `english`, but in the subsequent calls to `double.Parse` you forgot to send the culture info. It is likely to be the reason why your calculation of the total price is not working, whilst the calculation of the standard price works.